# Is it possible to set user agent in Chrometab in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, tabs

I am looking for a way to set user agent for chrome tab in android.We can do it in webview but my requirements doesn't want me to use webview. Is there any exposed api in chrome tab where I can set the user agent unlike other external browser and we don't have control to set the useragent. Please help.